# How to make only a get request on compoment click

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have decided to use Typescript for all my react applications but I am having a bit of a problem because of the learning curve. I have a problem when I click to users, it should make a get request on component did mount, but it continues endlessly, this is mostly a code from a template from the dotnet create react redux app and I took most of the code for granted.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { ApplicationState } from '../../store';
import * as UsersStore from '../../store/Users';

type UsersProps =
  UsersStore.UsersState &
  typeof UsersStore.actionCreators &
  RouteComponentProps<{}>;

class Users extends React.PureComponent<UsersProps> {
  public componentDidMount() {
    this.ensureDataFetched();
  }

  public componentDidUpdate() {
    this.ensureDataFetched();
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>Users</h1>
        {** // render users **}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  private ensureDataFetched() {
    const token = "web_token";
    this.props.requestUsers(token);
  }
};

export default connect(
  (state: ApplicationState) => state.users,
  UsersStore.actionCreators
)(Users as any);
```

And my: store, action, reducer

```js
import { Action, Reducer } from 'redux';
import { AppThunkAction } from './';
import userService from '../services/userService';
import { GET_USERS, GET_USER } from '../constants';

// STATE
export interface UsersState {
  isLoading: boolean;
  users: User[];
  user: User;
}

export interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

// ACTIONS
interface GetUserAction {
  type: 'GET_USER';
  payload: User;
}

interface GetUsersAction {
  type: 'GET_USERS';
  payload: User[];
}

type KnownAction = GetUserAction | GetUsersAction;

// ACTION CREATORS
export const actionCreators = {
  requestUsers: (token: string): AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    // Only load data if it's something we don't already have (and are not already loading)
    const appState = getState();
    if (appState && appState.users) {
      try {
        const users = await userService.getUsers(token);
        dispatch({ type: GET_USERS, payload: users })
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Bad request, please try loading again.')
      }
    }
  }
};

// REDUCER
const unloadedState: UsersState = { users: [], isLoading: false, user: { id: "0", name: "" } };

export const reducer: Reducer<UsersState> = (state: UsersState | undefined, incomingAction: Action): UsersState => {
  if (state === undefined) {
    return unloadedState;
  }
  const action = incomingAction as KnownAction;
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_USERS:
      if (state.users !== action.payload) {
        return {
          ...state,
          users: action.payload
        };
      }
      break;
    case GET_USER:
      return {
        users: state.users,
        isLoading: false,
        user: action.payload,
      };
  }
  return state;
};
```

UPDATE: Added this check but now it does not update users state, my idea is to check whether the current state is not the same as the payload then it updates otherwise it will skip and break.

```js
      if (state.users !== action.payload) {
        return {
          ...state,
          users: action.payload
        };
      }
      break;
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Your `componentDidUpdate()` is the one causing infinite rendering issue**

I can see that you already fetch the info in your `componentDidMount()`, so it's not necessary to fetch them over again.

- First, after your component is rendered `componentDidMount` is invoked
- Then your `ensureDataFetched` is fetched.
- Your redux state is changed
- Then your `componentDidUpdate` invoked due to that re-rendering
- Your redux state is changed again.
- Then your `componentDidUpdate` invoke all over again.
- Infinite loop...

**Just remove this block will end that endlessly rendering:**

```
public componentDidUpdate() {
    this.ensureDataFetched();
}
```

Comment: I did that before posting the question but it still behaves the same. Usually I check if there is a change between states and then decide to make another get request or not, but that is more like a hack I think, so I was thinking if I there is an actual solution for that.

Comment: I see, so you might want to add some conditions before invoking `ensureDataFetched` in your `componentDidUpdate()`.

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking if there is a standard way of doing or some conditional clauses would be sufficient?

Comment: Actually, there is no standard way when it comes to readability and extendability. Just code the way you think you meet those needs then it's fine.